# How to create a flyer with this layout?

Tags: multicol, flyers

I want to create a flyer with eight subpages inside a page, where all 8 pages must have borders. Which package should I focus on learning for this purpose?

[image: https://distritovegetal.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/20130321_172847.jpg]

Comment: Crosspost to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=26634#p91396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
\documentclass[21pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcounter{ct} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}

  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}

  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=8,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
  }

     \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%


    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

       \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%    

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%


    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{7}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%        

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{8}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%



\begin{document}

\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 9}{%
\blindtext
\clearpage

}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Remark: In slightly modified form (by re-arranging and rotating some of the pages) it can be used to create a "pocket mod": http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=909